# Split result of 'prompt()' into items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

**Question**

How can I add multiple values to a list just by using one `prompt();`?

**Code**

```
let items = [];
action = prompt("Enter");
```

If my input is `Hello World!`, then how can I make my list looking like this:

```
items = ["Hello", "World!"];
```

**Attempts**

This is the closest that I can get (it failed becasue I can only use one `prompt();`):

```
let first = prompt("Enter 1");
let second = prompt("Enter 2");
items.push(first);
items.push(second);
```

Comment: It depends on the separator you will be using, and do you mean by item? what's condiered to be an item?

Comment: Just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *split* the received string to get an *array* with two separate values.

```js
let action = prompt();
let items = action.split(' ');

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is like that?

```js
let items = [], action, i = 1;
  
while(action = prompt(`Enter ${i++}`)){
   items = items.concat(action.split(" "));
}
  
console.log(items);

//Enter 1: hello world
//Enter 2: four five
//[Cancel] prompt

//Result: ["hello", "world", "four", "five"]
```

[.split(" ")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) : Separate words by `space`

[.concat(items)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a) : To merge the current array with the previous array

Comment: No, when you cancel the prompt, the loop will end

Comment: Obviously it is not a precise example, but the condition can be adapted to the expectations of what is being worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by specifying a `whitespace` as separator.

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by
>   separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator
>   string to determine where to make each split.

For example :

```
let inputFromPrompt = prompt("Enter"); 
// then enter "Hello World!"
let token = inputFromPrompt.split(' ');
```

Comment: I am using ES6 syntax.

Comment: I updated with `let`. But note that `var` is  legal in ES6 and may be acceptable in a function.

Comment: @davidxxx Your example invokes `split` on an array. Can you include the `prompt` from the OPs code?